# Find manager in a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a Projects table with ID and Responsible manager. The Responsible manager columns has values as `John,Jim` for Project 1 and `Jim,Julie` for Project 2.

But if I pass Jim to my stored procedure I should get 2 projects (1,2). This returns no rows because the column is `John,Jim` but SQL Server is looking for `='Jim'`:

```
 select distinct ID,Manager from Projects where Manager=@Manager
```

Comment: Why are you storing a comma-separated list of manager names in a single column? Normalize. Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE ',' + Manager + ',' LIKE '%,Jim,%'
```

Or I suppose to match your actual code:

```
WHERE ',' + Manager + ',' LIKE '%,' + @Manager + ',%'
```

Note that your design is extremely flawed. There is no reason you should be storing names in this table at all, never mind a comma-separated list of any data points. These facts are important on their own, so treat them that way!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Managers
(
  ManagerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE, ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Projects
(
  ProjectID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE, ...
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProjectManagers
(
  ProjectID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Projects(ProjectID),
  ManagerID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Managers(ManagerID)
);
```

Now to set up the sample data you mentioned:

```
INSERT dbo.Managers(ManagerID, Name)
  VALUES(1,N'John'),(2,N'Jim'),(3,N'Julie');

INSERT dbo.Projects(ProjectID, Name)
  VALUES(1,N'Project 1'),(2,N'Project 2');

INSERT dbo.ProjectManagers(ProjectID,ManagerID)
  VALUES(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3);
```

Now to find all the projects Jim is managing:

```
DECLARE @Manager NVARCHAR(32) = N'Jim';

SELECT p.ProjectID, p.Name
  FROM dbo.Projects AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectManagers AS pm
  ON p.ProjectID = pm.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Managers AS m
  ON pm.ManagerID = m.ManagerID
  WHERE m.name = @Manager;
```

Or you can even manually short circuit a bit:

```
DECLARE @Manager NVARCHAR(32) = N'Jim';


DECLARE @ManagerID INT;
SELECT @ManagerID = ManagerID
  FROM dbo.Managers
  WHERE Name = @Manager;

SELECT p.ProjectID, p.Name
  FROM dbo.Projects AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.ProjectManagers AS pm
  ON p.ProjectID = pm.ProjectID
  WHERE pm.ManagerID = @ManagerID;
```

Or even more:

```
DECLARE @Manager NVARCHAR(32) = N'Jim';


DECLARE @ManagerID INT;
SELECT @ManagerID = ManagerID
  FROM dbo.Managers
  WHERE Name = @Manager;

SELECT ProjectID, Name
  FROM dbo.Projects AS p
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM dbo.ProjectManagers AS pm
      WHERE pm.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
      AND pm.ManagerID = @ManagerID
  );
```

As an aside, I really, really, really hope the `DISTINCT` in your original query is unnecessary. Do you really have more than one project with the same name *and* ID?

Comment: Yep! gotta distinguish between Jim and Jimmy!  For SQL Server would `CONTAINS()` be faster than `LIKE`?

Comment: @ebyrob Well, contains requires full-text search, so no easy answer there. My contention is that this data is stored wrong in the first place and a different design will ensure that you don't have to care what type of string search is faster.

Comment: No argument about normalization here.  I don't think you'd added that part when I commented...

Comment: @ebyrob no, answers are often a work in progress during the first minute. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In a `WHERE` clasue a `=` operator looks for an exact match. You can use a `LIKE` with wildcards for a partial match.

```
where Manager LIKE '%Jim%'
```

Comment: Except this will also find Jimbo and Bobby-Jim.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID,
    Manager 
FROM 
    Projects 
WHERE 
    (
     (Manager LIKE @Manager + ',*') OR
     (Manager LIKE '*,' + @Manager) OR
     (Manager  = @Manager) 
    )
```

That should cover both names and surnames, while still searching for literal values. Performance can be a problem however, depending on table

Comment: Is `*` supposed to be a wildcard here? That may work in Access (or other platforms), but not SQL Server. Also this assumes that there will only ever be a maximum of 2 managers on a project.

Answer (score 0):

please tried with below query

```
select distinct ID,Manager from Projects where replace('#$#' + Manager + '#$#', ',', '#$#') like '%Jim%'
```