# how to select entries by comparing two lists?

Tags: sql, db2

I need to select all entries where any item of a list is in some column

here is MY_TABLE:

```
     COLUMN1     COLUMN2       
        1        item1, item2, item3, item4  
        2        item5, item6, item7, item8  
        3        item9, item10, item11, item12  
        4        item13, item14, item15, item16  
        5        item17, item18, item19, item20
```

So I need something like:

```
    DECLARE @MY_LIST   
    SET MY_LIST =  "'item1', 'item15'"  
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE @MY_LIST IN COLUMN2
```

and it should return:

```
     COLUMN1     COLUMN2       
        1        item1, item2, item3, item4  
        4        item13, item14, item15, item16
```

MY_LIST can be an array and data in COLUMN2 we can convert into array as well.
So if there is an item in both MY_LIST and in COLUMN2 then I need this entry be selected.

Thank you very much for any response

Comment: Do you need that in SQL-PL or in PL/SQL? DB2 or Oracle? You tagged DB2, but your systax in closer to Oracle

Comment: sorry.. it's DB2... the syntax is just an example.. what I need in DB2

Comment: assume the syntax doesn't really matter... I can use another column with the items instead of MY_LIST variable... So I need to select all entries where at least one item from one column (or variable or array) is in list of items in another column

Comment: What type of platform is your DB2 server running on: IBM i, LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows), or z/OS? And what version of DB2?

Comment: what I know that DB2 version is 9.7.9 on Linux.. Does it matter for the syntax?..   I updated my initial question

Comment: This appears to be a comma-separated list stored in a single column, which is usually a bad idea for a db (it's usually better to have one item _per-row_).  Currently, you're looking at a full table scan (which will be slow for a large table), as I don't think DB2 does full-text indices...  This [`LIKE`-based answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18136190/812837) should work for DB2 as well, although you'll either need to 1) dynamically write the `OR` condition or 2) reference a temp-table.  Can you change how the data is stored?

Comment: well, I'm going to redesign my table.. and convert column 2 into another table with single entry for each item.. that works